# jar file making

Tags: java

I am trying to create a jar file with many classes. Using the following command

```
C:\Users\use\Desktop\SDE_7_SSH\eclipse\new\charge\src\jar> jar cf charge.jar *.class
```

But it is throwing an error **'jar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

In my jar folder (C:\Users\use\Desktop\SDE_7_SSH\eclipse\new\charge\src\jar), i am having two other folders named "f1", "f2", which inturn having classes.

Comment: When i try to use the following command, i am getting the error respectively C:\Users\use\Desktop\SDE_7_SSH\eclipse\new\charge\src\jar>java -jar
cf charge.jar *.class
Error: Unable to access jarfile cf it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the jar command from bin directory. For example on linux system, I would either go to my directory

> cd /usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_01/bin/

and then run

> jar cf charge.jar *.class

or else run it with the full path of java binary

> /usr/local/java/jdk1.6.0_01/bin/jar cf charge.jar *.class

Answer (score 0):

Use 'java -jar' Not just 'jar'

Comment: When i try to use the following command, i am getting the error respectively C:\Users\use\Desktop\SDE_7_SSH\eclipse\new\charge\src\jar>java -jar
cf charge.jar *.class
Error: Unable to access jarfile cf it is

Comment: `java -jar` is used to execute a JAR archive not to create one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the complete path to the jar program, which is in Java's bin directory. Like

> jdk_with_version\bin\jar cvf *.class

Comment: Since i am new to java, can you give me detailed example

Comment: Follo this link (www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/cit594-2002/Pages/jar-files.html) this could help you to solve

Comment: i am able to create jar file. But after adding the jar file to my project it is showing class not found errors. I checked my jar files by using the command D:\charge>D:\rrr\bkk\"core java"\software\Java\Java_1.6.0_
04_win\jdk1.6.0_04\bin\jar xvf  charge.jar. It is having the .java files, but i am getting class not found error in my project.

Comment: Extract your jar and see whether you could find the classes which your looking for?

Comment: Make sure whether you have added the jar file to the classpath in run configurations  and execute